# codebuild error exit status 127 - file name too long

Tags: amazon-web-services, cicd, aws-codebuild, amazon-ecr

I am not very experimented with aws, I am trying to build a docker image using codebuild to then send it to an ECR repositery.

here is my buildspec.yml file:

```yaml
version: 0.2

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws --version
      - $(aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION)

      - REPOSITORY_URI= {URI}
      - COMMIT_HASH=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
      - IMAGE_TAG=build-$(echo $CODEBUILD_BUILD_ID | awk -F":" '{print $2}')

  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...
      - docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest .
      - docker tag $REPOSITORY_URI:latest $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker images...
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
      - echo Writing image definitions file...
      - printf '[{"name":"{name}","imageUri":"%s"}]' $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG > imagedefinitions.json
      - cat imagedefinitions.json

artifacts:
  files: imagedefinitions.json
```

here is the error that I got:

```
[Container] 2023/11/15 10:40:59.168094 Running command $(aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION)
/codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: 4: {long base64 encoded string}: File name too long

[Container] 2023/11/15 10:40:59.876595 Command did not exit successfully $(aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION) exit status 127
[Container] 2023/11/15 10:40:59.879980 Phase complete: PRE_BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2023/11/15 10:40:59.879996 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: $(aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION). Reason: exit status 127
```

the base 64 string once decrypted gives:

```json
{
   "payload":"/{long string that looks randomly generated}",
   "datakey":"{long string but not as long as the previous one}",
   "version":"2",
   "type":"DATA_KEY",
   "expiration":1700088059
}
```

I have already attached "AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess" and "AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryPowerUser" policies and the default basepolicy to the service role associated with my build project

I am completely lost as I didn't find any info about that error on internet, and chatgpt didn't seem to help

Answer (score 4):

You aren't capturing the ECR login password and you aren't even attempting to pass it to Docker to login. Instead you are generating the ECR login password and then telling Linux to "run" the password like it's a path to a file.

You need to capture the password value in an environment variable:

```
- ECR_PASSWORD=$(aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION)
```

You also need to get the AWS account ID, for use in the docker login command:

```
- AWS_ACCOUNT_ID=$(aws sts get-caller-identity --query 'Account' --output text)
```

And then you need to actually send the password to Docker, to actually use it to login

```
- echo -n ${ECR_PASSWORD} | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com
```

---

All together:

```
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws --version
      - ECR_PASSWORD=$(aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION)
      - AWS_ACCOUNT_ID=$(aws sts get-caller-identity --query 'Account' --output text)
      - echo -n ${ECR_PASSWORD} | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com

      - REPOSITORY_URI= {URI}
      - COMMIT_HASH=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
      - IMAGE_TAG=build-$(echo $CODEBUILD_BUILD_ID | awk -F":" '{print $2}')
```

Comment: thank you a lot this worked! :D
and as I said, I am not very experimented with aws, so thank you for helping me out :p

Comment: Don't forget to double quote your variables. Also, what's `{URI}` ?

Comment: Also you should disable newlines when using `echo`, so `echo -n`

Comment: @Paolo good catch on the `echo -n`, I updated the answer. As for the `{URI}` thing, I just copied that part from the original question, to show where my updated code would go. It definitely looks like another error in the build though.

Comment: @1ups_ this isn't even AWS specific stuff, it's just basic Bash/Linux scripting stuff that you are missing.

Comment: @MarkB yeah, I think it should probably be `${URI}`

Comment: @Paolo yeah probably, but there isn't enough information provided in the question to know for sure. And the whole thing is just copying the value of one environment variable  to another environment variable, which seems pointless anyway.